# How to crop image in image picker before upload image in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

How to crop an image in image/file picker before upload image in ReactJs

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: checkout this blog post i recently published  - https://medium.com/swlh/adding-crop-before-upload-in-react-22dfcf3a95b7 - It can help get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is what you aim to achieve, but I implemented `cropper.js` framework to do so.

Comment: "react-avatar-edit"; this is what I am actually using and it's working but it converting my blob to base 64 can uh help me out ???? that third party package is here  [link](https://reactjsexample.com/reactjs-component-to-upload-and-preview-avatars/)

Comment: ok, and what is so wrong about it? as far as i can remember `cropper.js` did so too. i am not sure if i understand the actual obstacle you are facing